# Faking an SMS Sender

Tags: android, sms, inbox, sender-id

How can I populate the SMS Inbox with an Alphanumeric Sender ID?

```
ContentValues my_values = new ContentValues();
my_values.put("address", senderid);//sender name
my_values.put("body", myMessage[i]);
my_values.put("status",-1);
getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"), my_values);
```

I have tried to use this code, but I don't get a notification. 
Then I tried to create a fake SMS and it notifies, but I can't assign an alphanumeric sender ID as it's not supported.

How can I implement both alphanumeric sender ID and notifications?